# Trying to understand the correct way to create a static route in CentOS, please assist

Tags: linux, routing, centos6

I've been trying to understand what's the correct way to add a static route on a CentOS 6.x machine.
In some forums they say to create a file named `route-dev_name` (for example route-eth0) with the relevant route and place it in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` , in some forums they say the file should be named `static-routes` , in both cases I'm unable to set a static route. It seems like in some CentOS releases it works only when naming the file `route-dev_name` and in some it only works when naming the file `static-routes`..
Can anyone please assist me?
This is the content of my route file:

```
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.253 dev eth0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using different CentOS versions on different servers, but mainly CentOS 6.3-6.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RH style device dependent routes defined using `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-device` files has caused lots of problems.

So real sysadmins use only `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` file without device dependency:

```
any net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Problems:

- When physical devices are bonded, you need to remember to chance route-*device* file too
- When you reorganize adapters in a virtual machine.

Naturally one should always use **bridge** devices, so one could avoid route-*device* file problems.

Also notice the syntax in `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` file, sniplet from 
`/etc/init.d/network`:

```
    # Add non interface-specific static-routes.
    if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/static-routes ]; then
       if [ -x /sbin/route ]; then
           grep "^any" /etc/sysconfig/static-routes | while read ignore args ; do
               /sbin/route add -$args
           done
       else
           net_log $"Legacy static-route support not available: /sbin/route not found"
       fi
    fi
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a file in /etc/syconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

add add the following

```
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.253 dev eth0
```

I have always used this approach. I have found this to be the best approach.

FYI: Check -- https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html

Comment: Okay's that's the approach I've been using myself until now, but recently on CentOS 6.5 machines I find that the `route-devX` file is being ignored and the servers do not Up the route when the server is rebooted or the network service is being restarted, any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Not sure.. Does the interface come up on boot/restart?.. I do not have a CENTOS/RHEL 6.5 test box ATM.. I'm not sure if there is any change in ifup-routes on RHEL 6.5.

Comment: Yea the interfaces operate properly... only the route is not coming up and i'm talking about freshly installed machine or about 2-3 months old. Anyways, I see that I use the correct approach so i'll just accept your question, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way to add routes...

This file - `/etc/init.d/network` - is launched when the PC is booting, and it uses a file `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` to add static routes

You have to create it because it doesn't exist.

If you read carefully the file `/etc/init.d/network`, it reads in this file each line to add routes, those line must begin by "any", and "route add -" is already known.

So in the file you are going to create >> /etc/sysconfig/static-routes, you have to write :

```
any net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1 eth0
```

- where 10.0.0.0/24 is the network you want to reach (255.255.255.0 is the mask)
- where gw 192.168.0.1 is the gateway to reach (certainly the router)
- where eth0 is the interface where to use.

This is the best way for adding static routes, 1 file for everything (not X files for X interfaces)

Answer (score 2):

I always use the `route-ethX` file approach on my CentOS 6.4 and 6.5 :

Create/edit file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX` (where X is your interface number) and set your route in this file :

```
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.253 dev eth0
```

You can also edit this file using the following format (personally i prefer the first syntax) :

```
GATEWAY0=192.168.20.253
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
ADDRESS0=192.168.20.0
```

Then restart the network to apply the changes :

```
service network restart
```

Further reading : https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html

Answer (score 0):

In */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts* there's a script *ifup-routes*. It looks for files with the name route-dev_name, e.g. route-eth0.

Answer (score 0):

On my case the file "**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-device**" didnt exist.

I proceed to add the required network or ip on the file "**/etc/sysconfig/static-routes**" and to make it permanently, I rebooted the machine and it turned out working as expected.

it was done in a :
`cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`

Best regards,

Manuel Lazo